# easiest way to connect unpacked array on module interface in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

Here is an example below

```
module a_mod ( u );
input bit [2:0] u [1:0];
...
endmodule

module b_mod ();

bit [2:0] c1, c2;
a_mod a_mod_inst ( 
  .u ( {c1,c2} ) // won't work
);

endmodule
```

What's the easiest way of doing the hookup such that u[0] == c2 and u[1] == c1 ?

BTW, I know I can do what I show below, but looking for a more elegant alternative

```
bit [2:0] tmp_u [1:0];
assign tmp_u[0] = c2;
assign tmp_u[1] = c1;

a_mod a_mod_inst (
.u ( tmp_u )  // works for sure
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
bit [2:0] c1, c2;
a_mod a_mod_inst ( 
  .u ( '{c1,c2} ) // note the single quote before the open curly bracket
);
```

See IEEE1800-2012 Section 10.9. `'{` is used for assigning or passing unpacked arrays.